# How do I implement a deque in Solidity?

Tags: arrays, data-types

I have an array of finite size, say something like `uint[100] Arr;`.

My question is, if I want to continually push to this array, what happens if it already has 100 uints in it and I push another one? Will I crash? Or will it automatically pop out the first element?

If it does not pop out the first element, am I okay to do something like this:

```
if (Arr.length == 100) {
    delete Arr[0];
}
Arr.push(new_uint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `push` to an array of fixed size. (The code you wrote above would not compile.)

[`push`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#members) modifies an array's size, so it's an operation that doesn't make sense for a fixed-size array. It only exists for dynamic arrays.

**UPDATE**

I believe that `delete Arr[0]` is equivalent to `Arr[0] = 0`, so it's also not doing anything useful for you.

If you explain what you're trying to do, perhaps people can help more. (It looks like you're trying to implement a deque using a fixed-size array? But what is *supposed* to happen when you run out of space?)

**UPDATE 2**

Per the comments, it sounds like you just want a regular circular buffer.

Untested, but I believe this should work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CircularBuffer {
    uint[100] Arr;

    // Represents the index in the array of the oldest element
    uint8 start;

    // Represents the next position to write to
    uint8 end;

    // Represents the size of the data (max of 100)
    uint8 size;

    function append(uint value) public {
        Arr[end] = value;
        end = (end + 1) % 100;

        if (size < 100) {
            size += 1;
        } else {
            // start was just overwritten
            start = (start + 1) % 100;
        }
    }

    function enumerate() public {
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            uint value = Arr[(start + i) % 100];
            // do something with value here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In essence, I want to keep the last 100 records. I am trying to implement a deque with a maximum length of elements. So when that length is reached, the oldest element is popped. I guess it doesn't need to be a deque because I don't intend to pop from the other side. But hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Wapiti Yeah, sounds like a regular circular buffer will do. See my edit.

Comment: Wow, that is cool! It destroys the ordering of the records within the array but I can always get them in their temporal order because of the start index. Thanks;)

Comment: The `enumerate` function enumerates them in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I take it this is a standard data structure? I have not heard of it before.

Comment: Yeah, it's called a circular buffer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer.